# How to re-dimension an array as long as i want

Tags: java, jsp

I'd like to know if I can re-dimension an array as long as I want. I tried to do it and it seems there aren't any problems. I created an array with these steps

```
//step 1
String  parole[];

//step 1        
parole = new String[1];
parole[0] = "ciao";

 //step 1       
parole = new String[2];
parole[1] = "buongiorno";
```

I ask this beacuse there something in my mind that tells me that i can't do it. Maybe i read something somewhere someplace...

Comment: Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: You can, but you will have to copy over all data each time.

Comment: If you won't a `List` there is a whole API for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T[],%20int,%20int%29

Comment: here you will lose "ciao" in your first array when you perform thrid step 1. Use ArrayList instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can create a new array object and assign it to an array reference.

But if you expected that parole[0] would still have "ciao" in it after your last step, you're wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you need to copy the first array into a new one.

Check this sample code:

```
public class ArrayCp {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] primoArray = new String[1];
        primoArray[0] = "Ciao";
        // Copio il primo array nel secondo cambiandone la dimensione (secondo parametro)
        String [] secondoArray = Arrays.copyOf(primoArray, 2);
        secondoArray[1] = "Buona Sera";

        for(String s : secondoArray) {
            System.out.println("Elemento: " + s );
        }
    }
}
```

However is better going with an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> theArr = new ArrayList<String>();
theArr.add("Ciao");
theArr.add("Buona Sera");
theArr.add("Buona Notte");
```

and get back to a simple array with

```
String [] resArray = theArr.toArray(new String[theArr.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a "new String[]" is just that, making a NEW string array. This means that any data you previously had in the reference is overwritten by the "new" object. (If you had other references to the string[] it wouldn't be lost however)

So, in short, no, you cannot "re-dimension" an array.

In your case, it is probably best to use an ArrayList, which provides for dynamic resizing (and is much easier to work with).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @BigMike
You should try ArrayList because it has built in methods for capacity which is far better than we doing it manually.
It does the work in [amortized time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) which will be hard for us to achieve.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more details.